# Reuse existing firefox instance with selenium and capybara

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

currently during debug of test cases selenium is opening a new firefox window, in whatever desktop screen it chooses.  I want to be able to have selenium attach to the existing window (and not close the window when the test is over.)

I see this in the selenium documentation

```
webdriver.firefox.useExisting   Never use in production Use a running instance of firefox if one is present
```

but I do not see how to set it from rails/rspec/capybara

I have looked at the related SO answers, and they are more to do with attaching to a running test.  I just want to control where the window is, and be able have the window open with the developer console, so we can see what is going on, and finally have the window stay open at the end of the test

Comment: not understand correctly, do you want to run capybara with firefox via console interactively or want to switch to firefox instance not opened by capybara?

Comment: I want capybara when starting a selenium test to use an existing Firefox instance.  Normally it fires up a whole new instance and then destroy s it when done.  Based on the above selenium doc this should be posdible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the issue 2163 it was a feature of Selenium 1 and not implemented to Selenium 2 but still stays in documentation. Check this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2163).

Comment: that helps... at the bottom of the issue it does explain a work around that sort of helps as well in case anybody is interested

Comment: they are saying this feature is not in Selenium 2.